# Raster Precision QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, precision

I am using r.patch extension in QGIS to join a number of LiDAR tiles, some of which overlap hence i am carrying out this task before utilising in a hydraulic model.

R.Patch works fine, however the precision of the height data is given to 13/14 decimal places - this is causing issues in using the resultant Ascii file in ICM where it cannot read the data.

Is there a solution to reduce the number of decimal points to 2 places?

I am using Version 2.8 as my company hasn't updated the software.